# Cannot receive emails in SES sub-domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm trying to setup email retrieval on AWS SES via Terraform:

```
locals {
  emails-chat-replies-domain = "dev.chat.mydomain.com"
  ses-smtp-domain            = "inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
}
resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "chat-replies" {
  provider = aws.eu-west-1
  domain   = local.emails-chat-replies-domain
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "chat-replies-amazonses-verification-record" {
  provider = aws.eu-west-1
  zone_id  = data.aws_route53_zone.mydomain.zone_id
  name     = "_amazonses.${aws_ses_domain_identity.chat-replies.id}"
  type     = "TXT"
  ttl      = "600"
  records  = [aws_ses_domain_identity.chat-replies.verification_token]
}

resource "aws_ses_domain_identity_verification" "chat-replies-verification" {
  provider = aws.eu-west-1
  domain   = aws_ses_domain_identity.chat-replies.id

  depends_on = [aws_route53_record.chat-replies-amazonses-verification-record]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "chat-replies-mx" {
  provider = aws.eu-west-1
  zone_id  = data.aws_route53_zone.mydomain.zone_id
  name     = local.emails-chat-replies-domain
  type     = "MX"
  ttl      = "600"

  records = ["10 ${local.ses-smtp-domain}."]
}

resource "aws_ses_receipt_rule_set" "chat-replies" {
  provider      = aws.eu-west-1
  rule_set_name = "chat-replies"
}

resource "aws_ses_receipt_rule" "chat-replies" {
  provider      = aws.eu-west-1
  name          = "${local.deployment-name}-chat-replies-store"
  rule_set_name = aws_ses_receipt_rule_set.chat-replies.id
  recipients    = [local.emails-chat-replies-domain]
  enabled       = true
  scan_enabled  = true

  lambda_action {
    position        = 1
    function_arn    = aws_lambda_function.ses-chat-replies.arn
    invocation_type = "Event"
  }
}
```

However I an error from Mail Delivery Subsystem:

```
Address not found
Your message wasn't delivered to azerty@dev.chat.mydomain.com because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail.

Reporting-MTA: dns; googlemail.com
Received-From-MTA: dns; me@mycompany.com
Arrival-Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2023 00:56:52 -0800 (PST)
X-Original-Message-ID: <aa10938b-34c1-febd-5fcc-8f2130f46d5c@mycompany.com>

Final-Recipient: rfc822; azert@dev.chat.mydomain.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Remote-MTA: dns; inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com. (54.155.140.59, the
 server for the domain dev.chat.mydomain.com.)
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
Last-Attempt-Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2023 00:56:53 -0800 (PST)
```

even though `dig` has the `MX` record:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.12 <<>> dev.chat.mydomain.com MX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21674
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1472
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dev.chat.ninefive.io.          IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dev.chat.mydomain.com.   600     IN      MX      10 inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.254#53(192.168.0.254) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar 11 12:35:33 CET 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 101
```

Moreover my AWS Lambda isn't triggered.

Can you give me any hints?

Comment: Looks like you asked dig for the A record (the default). If you want to ask for an MX record, I believe you must specify. `dig dev.chat.mydomain.com MX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the rule wasn't active

```
resource "aws_ses_active_receipt_rule_set" "chat-replies" {
  rule_set_name = aws_ses_receipt_rule_set.chat-replies.id
}
```